# PHP programmers mention OOP for scalability, but what happened before OOP?

Tags: php, oop

i have been told that OOP will replace procedural programming in PHP because of scalability.My question is what happened before OOP? was no PHP program scalable before OOP? is it possible to build a program in PHP using procedural code to build a program that can scale?

1. What happened before OOP ?
2. Is it possible to build a program in PHP using procedural code to build a program that can scale?
3. Why the obsession with OOP? and or frameworks(codeigniter, laravel ect )?
4. Why not just use mostly functions or some other method, is this not making the learning curve take 
   years  and years for new programmers?
5. And why do i hear a lot of negativity  about relational databases? why is there a hype about non relational databases.

Whats your thoughts on this?

Comment: "What are tags for on Stack Overflow?" They are for the topics that are "relevant to your question" and those topics only. Please do to just tag questions with everything that your current "project" encompasses unless the question has something relevant to that tag. Also do not "tag" everything you think is "cool right now" just to bring attention to your question. But honestly, why Object Oriented programming? You deserve every bad answer you get. I wouldn't hold my breath for a good one. Welcome to the 21st century.

Comment: So many totally unrelated questions here, you should really have asked them as individual questions

Comment: I don't think OOP is directly involved in scalability. "*i have been told that OOP will replace procedural programming in PHP*" - Procedural programing in PHP is like stone age. OOP in PHP was available in PHP 4 and since PHP 5 it was well improved.

Comment: `And why do i hear a lot of negativity about relational databases? why is there a hype about non relational databases` - because a lot of people (erroneously) believe that nosql databases are better than relational databases.... they're wrong because relational databases are better at some things, nosql databases better at others, and often it depends on the type of data that you're working with as to which one you should use.... sometimes, it's even best to use a combination of both

Comment: @NeilLunn Eh? Why remove the "oop" tag? This question is more about OOP than it is about PHP!

Comment: @chiastic-security That was probably overkill, but I was mostly talking about all the other tags originally added. On first glance you might actually tap on some real concepts here so I guess I'll give it a read. But I still really hold the opinion that a really good answer would push the limits of what you can post here. And probably therefore should just be a link in closing a "very broad" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that this isn't really anything specific to PHP. Object-oriented programming was a revolution in programming generally.

But for your specific questions:

1. Before OOP, programmers had a harder job of keeping conceptually separate things separate in the code. If you want all your code relating to dogs in one place, it's much easier to do this with OOP. It can be done with procedural programming, if you're careful and have good code structure, but it's certainly messier and harder to deal with.
2. Yes, it's possible to write scalable procedural code. It does depend a little on what you mean by *scalable*, though. If you mean *scaling to large amounts of data*, then there's no real issue. If you mean *scaling to ever larger programs and more and more functionality*, then it's harder without OOP, but it can be done (and had to be done before OOP came in). This is really about *extensibility* and *maintainability* rather than scalability, though.
3. The obsession with OOP is because it much better matches the way we think. You write a `Dog` class, and it encapsulates all the doggy data and all the doggy functionality. Without OOP, you have to keep your data and your code separate; but that's artificial in some ways. When we think about a dog, we think about what data it holds (colour, size, breed) *and* what it can do (woof, run) all together. OOP enables this. Frameworks are a little different: they deal with things that lots of programs need to do, and would have to do for themselves if there were no framework. It is a way of saving programmers lots of time and effort and debugging, by doing lots of the work for them, and allowing them to concentrate on what's specific to their application.
4. There is a difference of opinion here as to whether it's best to teach OOP right from the beginning or whether to add it in later, after teaching procedural programming. The argument in favour of early objects is that it's more conceptual; but on the other hand it does mean teaching a whole lot more language features right from the start.
5. For anything, anywhere, in any context, someone is going to be negative about it! So I wouldn't get too worked up about this. Certainly relational databases have their limitations: they don't neatly capture objects, for instance, and you end up with frameworks whose entire purpose is to translate between the object world and the relational database world (ORMs, or Object-Relational Mappings). But don't be fooled by the negativity: relational databases are still standard fare in all types of programming, and they're not disappearing any time soon.

Comment: Should we throw the functional programming paradigm into the mix as well, just to complicate things still further :) Good answer

Comment: @MarkBaker That went through my mind when I said that OOP had revolutionized *programming generally* :) I thought about a footnote in case of pedantry, but...

Comment: You completely lost me on point 5 as that is a very silly statement. Non-Relational datastores existed for a long time before relational and solved a certain set of problems. Guess what, we're back there again for a certain set of problems. The only true thing there is "not going away" and they should not for the the problem set that is solved. But nothing to do with OOP really other than mentioning the impedance mismatch. Nice try, but the question is way too broad really.

Comment: thanks @chiastic-security for your well explained answers.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I had the *post-*relational world in mind here (NoSQL etc.). That's where most of the recent negativity comes from: claims that relational databases are old hat. I wasn't thinking of the *pre-*relational world.

Comment: @NeilLunn And I've just learnt something myself: that asterisks don't generate italics in comments if the closing asterisk appears in the middle of a word! Who knew?!

Comment: Well "pre-relational" did exist, and funny enough has more of a direct relation to OOP than relational did. Comes out like a tongue twister that doesn't it. Anyhow, that is more of a *fact* than the statement given

Comment: hehe. The stupid thing here is that *they do*. See, italics there. But not when paired with a `-` as you did. Better answer given so far but I see this question being removed, so don't feel too great about the points. Ce la vie

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I've just discovered it's related to the hyphen. I've [reported the bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272906/why-doesnt-pre-relational-generate-italics-for-pre).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific PHP thing, PHP just was a little slower // made the change differently.

Before OOP there was procedural code. Then someone thought of a different way to look at programs, which was deemed 'better' certain tasks/programs. You can read a lot on the hows and why's, but the bottomline isn't that a lot of things are impossible without OOP, it is just that it might be harder. So before OOP it was business a usual, but without this "trick".

As your other questions: bigger problems require a different way of working then smaller ones. SUre, that may give you some learning curve, but guess what: harder things take time to learn. Just like a warehouse: why should you use some complicated scheme that amazon uses to put stuff in a warehouse, why not just stack it? Well, the answer is that is works better for a big warehouse. But it is really hard to make an automated warehouse like that! doesn't that make it that it takes you years to make something like that? Sure it does. Doesn't mean it's a bad thing, it just means you might not want your garage ordered in that way.

The point is, as you are making bigger projects, you will be looking for more structure and ways to work on older code: make changes easier (e.g.:which of your big list of functions have to change if you change this field in  the database?), making testin easier, etcetc.

What relational databases have to do with this, I don't know. Maybe open up a second question instead, .